# Activity Indicator while calling API

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to display the activity indicator while waiting for the API to return. The problem is after all the result I get from API, then the spinner only display. The result I want is while waiting for API call, then the spinner will running.

I'm calling this method in here

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section { 
   [self startLoadingSpinner]
   //Calling API...
   [self stopLoadingSpinner]
}
```

Here is the method for the activity indicator

```
-(void)startLoadingSpinner {
    self.activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 70)];
    self.activityIndicator.opaque = YES;
    self.activityIndicator.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.4f];
    self.activityIndicator.center = self.view.center;
    self.activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray;
    [self.activityIndicator setColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:self.activityIndicator];
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
}
```

This is how I stop the activity indicator

```
-(void)stopLoadingSpinner {
    [self.activityIndicator performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
}
```

Comment: `Calling API...` code?

Comment: Calling API in numberOfRowsInSection? O_O

Comment: provide your API calling code.

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Don't add activity indicators in tableview datasource method - `numberOfRowsInSection` .

Add these two functions calling in the same method where you are making an API call. Make an API call in **ViewDidLoad**, some **life cycle method** or in **action methods**.

Below is the example of using it.

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://httpbin.org/get"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

[self startLoadingSpinner]

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@ %@", response, responseObject);
    }

    [self stopLoadingSpinner]
}];
[dataTask resume];
```

In **Swift**

```
func makeAPIRequest(to endPoint: String) {

    // here you can showActivetyIndicator start progressing here
    self.startLoadingSpinner()   
    Alamofire.request(endPoint).responseJSON{ response in
        if let value = response.result.value {
            let responseInJSON = JSON(value)
            self._responseInJSON = responseInJSON
        }
       // here you can hide Your ActivetyIndicator here
      self.stopLoadingSpinner()
    }
}
```

Comment: but OP wants objC bruh.

Comment: Yes. Please wait. I'm making changes

Comment: Edited the answer @GeneCode. Thanks ;-)

Comment: While making an API call, If you are loading spinner means the user is not going to use UI for some time. In case if still we want user to make interactions with app? then I don't recommend loading on main thread

Comment: Read my comment carefully. I said ___inside block___. If you still don't get it, study "updating UI after asynchronous API callback".

Comment: What nayem says is "[self stopLoadingSpinner]" should be called on main thread. as your code now updates the UI on the background process (NSURLSession)

Comment: The result still the same =(

Comment: use grand central dispatch. i cant remember the code syntax. but u can search gcd main thread on google that should give the result.

Comment: Nur II below I set the code and please check my answer.Everything is in below answer.

Answer (score 0):

My detailed answer is below

```
-(void)simpleGetResponse{
    @try {
            //Call the Activity Indicator show method here
            [self startLoadingSpinner];
            NSString *strURL = @"Your URL";
            NSURL *urlStr = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
            NSMutableURLRequest *mutaURL = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:urlStr];
            [mutaURL setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
            NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
            NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:mutaURL completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
                                              {
                                                  NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
                                                  if(httpResponse.statusCode == 200)
                                                  {
                                                      NSError *parseError = nil;
                                                      id response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];
                                                      if(response != nil){
                                                          if([response isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
                                                              NSLog(@"response is in dictionary format %@",response);
                                                              NSDictionary *dictRes = [response copy];
                                                              NSLog(@"The dictRes is - %@",dictRes);
                                                          }
                                                          else{
                                                              NSLog(@"response is in array format %@",response);
                                                              NSDictionary *arrRes = [response copy];
                                                              NSLog(@"The arrRes is - %@",arrRes);
                                                          }
                                                          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                             //Call the Activity Indicator hidden method inside the dispatch_main_queue method
                                                             [self stopLoadingSpinner]
                                                             [yourTableView reloadData];
                                                          });
                                                      }
                                                  }
                                                  else
                                                  {
                                                      NSLog(@"Error");
                                                  }
                                              }];
            [dataTask resume];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [exception description]);
    }
    @finally {
    }
}
```